# Make a single view application to table view application

Tags: ios, xcode, tableview

I made a single view application. It's kind of an alarm app. And like the alarm app in the iPhone(which is basically provided in the iOS) if I tap the plus button, I want the application to make a cell in the table view, and when I tap the cell, I want the single view(which I have already made) to appear. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some steps to move forward:

- To add 1 cell when you tap + button:
  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/TableMultiSelect/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011189
- To tap the cell -> separate view:
  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/NavBar/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007418

try to download and investigate the sample code from apple. hope it helps.